# Stripe checkout + TaxJar: Display tax amount on top of item price

Tags: stripe-payments

I have registered Stripe and TaxJar accounts, entered TaxJar provided URL into Stripe account settings.

So, my question is:
Is there a way to display total amount to charge, using [Item price + Tax] scheme on the Stripe checkout button and to charge this amount?

Or I must use custom checkout and add JS calculations myself? If so, could you please point me, where can I start?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stripe Checkout doesn't support dynamic tax calculation at the moment. You'll need to handle this calculation on your end instead.

The idea would be that you'd integrate TaxJar in your own application to be able to calculate the tax needed for a given customer and charge amount. Once you have that information, you can calculate the total amount to charge and pass this amount to Checkout to display properly.

You should contact TaxJar directly for help on how to integrate their API in your system or to see if they offer a checkout flow that would do this for you on their end.